# Help solving the limit of the sequence: $\left( \frac{2n^2 - 1}{2n^2 + 1} \right) ^ { \left( \frac{2n^3 - n}{n + 3} \right) }$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Given the following sequence,

$$\left( \frac{2n^2 - 1}{2n^2 + 1} \right) ^ { \left( \frac{2n^3 - n}{n + 3} \right) }$$
I am asked to determine to which $l \in \mathbb{R}$ the sequence converges.

This is what I have tried so far:

$$
\lim_{n} \left( \frac{2n^2 - 1}{2n^2 + 1} \right) ^ { \left( \frac{2n^3 - n}{n + 3} \right) } \implies
\left( \frac{2n^2 + 1}{2n^2 - 1} \right) ^ { - \left( \frac{2n^3 - n}{n + 3} \right) }  \implies 
\left( \frac{2n^2}{2n^2 - 1} + \frac{1}{2n^2 - 1} \right) ^ { - \left( \frac{2n^3 - n}{n + 3} \right) } \implies 
\left( 1 + \frac{1}{2n^2 - 1} \right) ^ { - \left( \frac{2n^3 - n}{n + 3} \right) } \implies ? $$

My objective was to algebraically modify the sequence such that I could be able to reduce it to the form: $$\lim _{x\to +\infty }\left(1+{\frac {1}{x}}\right)^{x}=e$$
but seem to be stuck at the `?` point.

Any suggestion? Thank you.

Comment: Numerically it seems pretty much that I get $\frac{1}{e^2}$ as limit.

Answer (score 2):

Hint

$$=\left(\left(1-\dfrac2{2n^2+1}\right)^{-(2n^2+1)/2}\right)^{-\frac{2(2n^3-n)}{(2n^2+1)(n+3)}}$$

Alternatively

$$=\left(\dfrac{(1-1/2n^2)^{2n^2}}{(1+1/2n^2)^{2n^2}}\right)^{\dfrac{2n^3-n}{2n^2(n+3)}}$$

Now the numerator converges to $e^{-1}$

What about the denominator & the exponent?

Answer (score 2):

Use$$\ln l=\lim_{n\to\infty}2n^2\underbrace{\frac{1-1/(2n^2)}{1+3/n}}_{\sim1}\underbrace{\ln\underbrace{\frac{1-1/(2n^2)}{1+1/(2n^2)}}_{1-1/n^2+o(1/n^2)}}_{\sim-1/n^2}=-2\implies l=e^{-2}.$$